# How to make Group Input node use angle with Degrees?

Tags: interface, mathematics, shader-nodes, conversion

In the *Shader Editor* I have created A Node Group and within this group I want to get an angle from the group input and do something with it.

If I simply create a new node input I am only allowed to have as input type *Vector*, *Shader*, *Float* or *Color*, if I choose *Float* I can then set *Min* and *Max* value to 0 and 360 and  connect that to *Combine Vector* and use the vector in a *Mapping* node like so:

[image: current setup]

This will not work as the input node value is in Degrees and the *Combine* + *Mapping* expect Radians.

I could add two *Math* nodes and covert from degrees to Radians `x*Pi/180` or I could just temporarily connect an angle input from an *Vector Rotate* node like this:

[image: vector rotate node]

For the group input to create a Degree input for me, like so:

[image: result group input]

So my question is: How to make an input accept angle Degrees ° ?

I have tried to input things like:

- 45d
- 45r
- 45°
- "45r"

But none worked.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add Units in the Input Parameters of Geometry Nodes properties panel?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/258623/how-to-add-units-in-the-input-parameters-of-geometry-nodes-properties-panel)

Answer (score 4):

You can use Math node to convert degrees to radians:

[image]

Even Rotation input displays Degrees, but actually it uses Radians. That design flaw is considered as known issue:

https://developer.blender.org/T81389

It is like you can enable metric system to view distance in meters, radians are viewed in degrees by default:

[image]

Comment: If you connect the ANGLE node from a VECTOR Rotate node into the GROUP Input node you will see that MAGICALLY an degrees input is created

Comment: Oh, that's fun. So I've learned that it has an internal property bl_socketname  'NodeSocketFloat' and 'NodeSocketFloatAngle'. Then I try to change that, Blender crashes. So it is not supposed to be changed, I guess. So at least for now, this question seems to duplicate of this one: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/258623/how-to-add-units-in-the-input-parameters-of-geometry-nodes-properties-panel

Comment: Thanks for that! so there is actually a property for an input to be either Float or Float Angle, very interestingm, but how come I can change any input socket from Float to FloatAngle just by attaching the Angle input of a Vector Rotate? this puzzles me

Comment: Once created, it can't be changed. Only in properties panel. But where is no units there. So it is design flaw