# What is the parameter forcing a node input defined as float to use degree unit for input?

Tags: geometry-nodes

After some experimentation in geometry nodes I noticed some of my root group inputs are using degree as their unit, which in my case makes sense, but I can't remember what I did to switch to this unit, or even if I actually did something.

My inputs are defined as floats apparently.

[image]

Note 180 is recognized as a half turn, meaning not only a degree unit is displayed, but the conversion degree-->radian is also performed under the hood. I can't reproduce this starting from scratch and using the same nodes:

[image]

I noticed the type of links used with the input appears different (discrete vs. multiple), but this difference seems only due to the behavior of the `Combine XYZ` node, e.g. both nodes with unconnected outputs:

[image]

---

Do I miss something obvious to select no unit or degree unit in the socket definition? Or is this a side effect from some previous operation? How to assign degrees to the newly created group inputs?

---

[image]

Comment: This is actually very similar question to this: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/271457/how-to-make-group-input-node-use-angle-with-degrees/271458#271458

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add Units in the Input Parameters of Geometry Nodes properties panel?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/258623/how-to-add-units-in-the-input-parameters-of-geometry-nodes-properties-panel)

Comment: @Crantisz, Both links are relevant. However none of the questions have yet an extensive answer, details are scattered (the reason it happens, how to remove it, the fact it is mostly a hidden parametrization, etc). Beyond my own interest, I think it would be interesting for the community to merge all these questions and provide a complete answer.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann can you undelete? :) Cheers!

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady Let's clean up the topic and collect all the answers at a single point.

Comment: @quellenform I think considering it's chronologically the first Q&A, it makes sense. We could ask Crantisz to move the answer there, and I could redact the question.

Comment: @Crantisz pinging

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady Yes, that sounds reasonable! (Even if the chronology is indeed not the priority here, but the quality of the question / answers! Therefore, I would actually prefer your question / answer as a target, but you decide) ...It is indeed a "missing feature" that a moderator cannot move answers ;-)

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady Thanks for your help in bringing these valuable posts together into one! Please forgive me if I jumped the gun here, but it wasn't entirely clear to me which post was a duplicate of which other post. I'm sorry if I've robbed you of your well-deserved reputation points by doing so. From my point of view, this question should have been recognized as a duplicate much earlier, but everything is just not always optimal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The parameter is `bl_socket_idname`. For regular value it is `NodeSocketFloat`, for radians is `NodeSocketFloatAngle`.

[image]

Unfortunately, there is no way to edit them at this point of time. You may only remove and make new. Then I was trying to set it manually using blender python API, blender crashed.