# Geometry Nodes: Duplicating Circle Index Broken?

Tags: geometry-nodes

Trying to do a simple equation to evenly distribute this mesh in a circle.
This (in my imagination) would be the same as selecting the mesh, hitting Sft+D, R, Z "18", and then Shft R 20 times.
For whatever reason, I'm getting these gaps. Seems like "index" doesn't work correctly?
[image]

Comment: pls provide blend file so we don't have to rebuild it manually. You want free help from us in our spare time, so pls make it as easy as possible for us to help you. thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$360° / 20 = 18°$$

Blender operates on radians. Sometimes it allows you to input an angle in degrees, but then it is indicated with a degree° symbol.

You're not inputting $18°$, you're inputting $18$. You could [set the subtype](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/283970/60486) of group input, to input an angle value in degrees:

[image]

Or you could manually input the value in radians, which the degree inputs are converted to, or use a math node to recalculate to the value in radians:

[image]

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH!
I was banging my head on this one for far too long.