# How to rotate each duplicate geometry about its origin from the duplicate geometry nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes

What I am trying to do: Duplicate the input mesh and place each at the same spot (overlapping) and have each duplicate rotated by a portion of tau (e.g. if 6 duplicates then each would be rotated by a 6th of a full rotation), and then boolean intersect them. I am new to geometry nodes and am using Blender 3.6 LTS (can go to 4.1 alpha if necessary).

I'm having some trouble determining how I could rotate each instance. For example, I started off by copying the example from the [duplicate elements](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/3.2/modeling/geometry_nodes/geometry/duplicate_elements.html) docs of how to do an array modified in geometry nodes, but I got stuck because there's no set rotation node.

Here is what I have so far (minus the boolean operation), however, all it seems to be doing is distributing points on the original mesh.

[image: attempt at geo nodes implementation]

Here's the placement of the objects using layout mode before the intersection operations. Using layout just to describe the operations I want to do in geometry nodes. In my node setup, I only have 1 monkey object and I am trying to do everything else procedurally.

I was not able to get the intersection to work correctly in layout mode either as an entire mouth and ears were remaining after all intersections, which shouldn't be the case.

[image: layout mode only]

Comment: sounds for me a bit contradictory if you want boolean intersect AND overlapping. Maybe add an image or sketch, how your end result should look like?

Comment: @Chris I've corrected the ordering of my steps as I had them out of order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out how to do it. They won't be perfectly brought to the center, but for my purposes it doesn't need that level of precision.

[image: node graph]

Comment: You can capture the rotation obtained from "Align Euler to Vector" (Have you tried using "Rotation" from the "Curve to Points" instead?), then scale points to 0 ("Transform Geometry" node), and proceed to use the "Instance on Points". Also see: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/303676/60486